# ¿Cómo cargar datos de una estructura en un archivo de texto?

Tags: c, archivo, struct

Lo que intento es que en el archivo de texto almacene la información de la función `altacontacto`, pero al abrir el archivo se genera la información mas caracteres aleatorios.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char nombre[15];
    char apellidop[15];
    char apellidom[15];
    char telefono[10];
    char correo[50];
} CONTACTO;
```

Ésta es mi estructura en la que almacena los datos.

```
char altacontacto(CONTACTO *cnt);
void guardarcontactoarchivo(CONTACTO *cnt);

int main()
{ CONTACTO cnt;
  
  altacontacto(&cnt);
  guardarcontactoarchivo(&cnt);
  
  return 0;
}

char altacontacto(CONTACTO *cnt)
{   
    printf("Ingrese los valores para la estructura:\n");
    printf("Numero de registro: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i",&cnt->id);
    printf("Nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&cnt->nombre);
    printf("Apellido paterno: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&cnt->apellidop);
    printf("Apellido materno: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&cnt->apellidom);
    printf("Telefono celular: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&cnt->telefono);
    printf("Correo electronico: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&cnt->correo);
    return cnt;
}
```

En esta función hago que se almacenen los datos en la variable `cnt` para después utilizarlos.

```
void guardarcontactoarchivo(CONTACTO *cnt)
{
    FILE * ArchivoSalida;
    
    ArchivoSalida=fopen("Texto.txt","wt");
    
    if(ArchivoSalida!=NULL)
    {   //Si se creo el archivo
        //fputs(&cnt, ArchivoSalida);
        printf("\nArchivo modificado exitosamente.");
        fwrite(&cnt,sizeof(CONTACTO),cnt->id,ArchivoSalida);
        fclose(ArchivoSalida);
    }
    else //No se creo el archivo
        printf("\nError al crear el archivo.");
    
}
```

Aquí es donde intento guardar los datos en un archivo, al revisarlo si aparecen los datos pero tambien aparecen caracteres aleatorios; además de aparecer toda desordenada la información.

Comment: ¿ Que significa `aparecer toda desordenada la información` ?

Comment: Bueno, al momento de revisar el archivo aparece algo así:
"1a     &@NOMBRE       ,     apellidopaterno'@               apellidomaterno*I" ; es decir, los datos registrados con otros símbolos y tabulaciones intermedias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar la función fwrite por esta:

```
fwrite(&cnt,sizeof(CONTACTO),1,ArchivoSalida);
```

Entiendo que el fichero que te crea no es de texto y de ahí los caracteres raros, no veras el id bien porque es un entero en la estructura y no una cadena de caracteres.

El tercer parámetro de fwrite es el numero de registros o contactos guardados( creo que uno en tu caso) y no el id. A saber lo que te guarda si pones mas de uno, lo que hay en memoria libre digamos.

Answer (score 0):

[`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) recibe un puntero a la información a escribir. `cnt` ya es un puntero, por lo tanto no tiene sentido obtener un puntero a un puntero.

Además, `cnt` es un parámetro que vive como variable local de la función. Así que la dirección de `cnt` será diferente a la de la variable original. Probablemente sea por eso que ves letras raras.

Por otro lado, el 2º parámetro de `fwrite` indica el tamaño de cada elemento a escribir y el 3º la cantidad de elementos a escribir. No es un desplazamiento. Cómo quieres escribir un solo elemento debería ser 1. Así:

```
fwrite(cnt, sizeof(CONTACTO), 1, ArchivoSalida);
```